# stuck in a while True loop which I can't seem to break

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck in a while True loop which I can't seem to break, any suggestions please:

```
minstops = 1
maxstops = 100
minpass = 0
maxpass = 35

print ("Please enter the route number")
route = input()

print("Please enter number of stops on" , route,".")
stops = int(input())

while stops != "x":
    while True:
        if stops >= minstops and stops <= maxstops:
            break
        else:
            print ("Please enter a number between",minstops,"and",maxstops,".")

print ("Please enter the number of people already on",route,".")
numofpassonbus = int(input())
```

Comment: Where inside your loop is `stops` *changed*?

Comment: stops is an `int()`, why are you comparing it with `"x"`?

Comment: Also, you have **two** `while` loops, remove the outer, it serves no purpose. `stops` can never be equal to a string, as you converted it to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You need an x=='x' to break the first while loop while you give an int to disrupt the second one. I would suggest you try to not use stops as int and string.